# Java Lambda | Find position first occurrence of an array of strings in a string

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I want to build a method `int getIndexOfFirstFound(String text, String[] words)`.

The method receive a text and array of words and should return the index of the first word found.

I know to do it with simple iteration, like this:

```
for (String word : words) {
    if (text.indexOf(word) != -1) return text.indexOf(word);
}
return -1;
```

but for my training I look how to do it with lambda, if it possible.
I know I can check if the string contain a word from the array: `Arrays.stream(words).parallel().anyMatch(text::contains)` but I don't know how to return the index..

How can I find the first found word index in a modern way?

Example:

`Text` = "Hello I'm your text, how are you?"
`Words` = ["your", "are"]

The result should be index of "your" (10).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simplest equivalent of your for loop is

```
int getIndexOfFirstFound(String text, String[] words) {
    return Arrays.stream(words)
            .mapToInt(text::indexOf)
            .filter(i -> i >= 0)
            .findFirst()
            .orElse(-1);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! working great and easy to understand :)

Comment: This returns the index of the first string in the array that's in the string. First as in order of array not in index within text. It's the same as your code but not the way I'd understand your requirements.

Comment: @Nicktar The example given matches the code for loop code, so I guess the description of the requirement needs an edit.

Comment: @Nicktar, not really understand the diff. but looks like it's what i'm looking for..

Comment: @AsfK see my answer, this is to long for a coment.

Answer (score 3):

Not the same result as your code but closer to my understanding of your requirements

```
int getIndexOfFirstFound(String text, String[] words) {
    return Arrays.stream(words)
            .mapToInt(text::indexOf)
            .filter(i -> i >= 0)
            .sorted()
            .findFirst()
            .orElse(-1);
}
```

Difference:

`Text` = "Hello I'm your text, how are you?" `Words` = ["are", "your"]

Your code would return 25 (index of 'are'), my code would return 10 (index of 'your')

Comment: actually I not care from the order so ernest answer is good for me. thank you too! it's good point to pay attention!

Answer (score 2):

I think for better performance with non-stream version you can do like this:

If `words`'s length is not so much, don't need to use `wordsSet`

```
int getIndexOfFirstFound(String text, String[] words) {
    int index = 0;
    Set<String> wordsSet = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(words));
    for (String w : text.split("\\s")) {
        if (wordsSet.contains(w)) break;
        index += (w.length()) + 1; // 1 is for the space between words in the text.
    }
    return index;
}
```

Comment: love it :) Thanks!